# Editar div contenedor dependiendo del hijo

Tags: html, css, selectores

*¿Se puede editar un elemento dependiendo del hijo que contiene?*

```
<div>
    <section id="content-area">Soy el hijo de div</section>
</div>
```

```css
div < #content-area{
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Cuando tenemos un elemento hijo, en el css solo debemos especificar quién es el padre para poderlo editar, en algunos casos se usa el símbolo > (mayor que) para determinar quién es el padre y quién es el hijo, y quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de poder editar al padre utilizando el identificador del hijo, o no sé si existe algo parecido como lo planteé en el css anterior, utilizando el símbolo < (menor que) donde #content-area es hijo de `div`, a div poderle poner un borde rojo solo cuando sea padre de `#content-area`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por qué no intentas hacerlo con js y jquery, empleando el método "parent"

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>parent demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="selected"><p>Hello Again</p></div>
 
<script>
$( "p" ).parent( ".selected" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actualmente con **CSS** no se puede lograr lo que quieres.

En los selectores de cuarto nivel de **CSS** se ha implementado la `pseudo-clase` [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:has) que permite seleccionar un elemento que tenga los elementos hijos que sean pasados como parámetro.

**Ejemplo:**

> El siguiente selector  selecciona únicamente los elementos `<a>` que contienen `<img>`

```
a:has(> img)
```

El problema de esta `pseudo-clase` es que aún no es soportada por ningún navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual la única solución posible es usar **JavaScript** ya sea deforma nativa o con algunas de sus librerías como por ejemplo **jQuery**

**Ejemplo con JavaScript**

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var titulo = document.querySelector('h1');

  titulo.parentNode.style.border = 'solid 1px red';
  titulo.parentNode.style.background = '#ccc';
  titulo.parentNode.style.padding = '10px';
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
</div>
```

**Ejemplo con jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1').parent('#contenido').css({
    'border':'solid 1px red',
    'background': '#ccc',
    'padding': '10px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenido">
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Están desarrollando el selector "has" para css (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:has), pero aún no hay ningún navegador corriente que lo soporte, sería así:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <style>
        div:has(> section#content-area) {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <div>
            <section id="content-area">Soy el hijo de div</section>
        </div>

        <div>
            <section >Soy el hijo de div falso</section>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aunque como no está soportado, solo te queda javascript como sugiere Jorge Luis